Serialization.writePretty format JSON the same way that pre-commit-hooks pretty-format-json does
I'm coding in Scala, using these packages package org.json4s package jackson and the function writePretty of Serialization class.
The thing is it's not formatted the way that pre-commit-hooks pretty-format-json does.
I want to edit the formatting rules on scale side to match pre-commit-hooks.
Which means no space before ":", no space for empty array, one line per element for not empty array
Like this
{
     "name": "John",
     "age": 30,
     "city": "New York"
}

Does there are any way to configure writePretty without recoding a PrettyPrinter?
I expected this result (pre-commit-hooks pretty-format-json result)
{
     "name": "John",
     "age": 30,
     "city": "New York"
     "misc": [],
     "required": [
        "name"
     ]
}

not this:
{
     "name" : "John",
     "age" : 30,
     "city" : "New York"
     "misc" : [ ],
     "required" : [ "name" ]
}

------ EDIT ------
I found a solution, maybe not the most elegant one, but it works:
instead using only
Serialization.writePretty(jsonSchema)

val printer: PrettyPrinter = new DefaultPrettyPrinter()
      .withObjectIndenter(new DefaultIndenter("  ", "\n"))
      .withArrayIndenter(new DefaultIndenter("  ", "\n"))
JsonMethods.mapper.setDefaultPrettyPrinter(printer)
Serialization.writePretty(jsonSchema).replace("\" :", "\":").replace("[ ]", "[]") + "\n"


So, you're asking how to pretty print JSON in a custom way with Jackson, right?

Note that all your examples use a single quote whereas JSON is double quotes (for keys and strings).

For the first question: yes
-> I took an online, ok I change the quotes
